# Forms - Not allow user to submit with incorrect phone and email

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, submit

Currently a user who fills out the input fields in my form is allowed to click the submit button even if it shows that the email and phone fields are invalid.  Currently my JavaScript is set up so the submit button will become not disabled and allow the user to click 'submit' just as long as if there is some text in the input fields.  Is there a way I can only allow the user to click submit if the correct and valid information is provided within the input fields.  If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it.
[image: Not Allowing User to Submit]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvffpjxb/16/)

First Name
                
              
              Last Name
                
              
              Email
                Please enter a valid email address
                
              
              Phone
                Please enter a valid phone number              
                
              
              City
                
              
              State/Province
                
              
              Company
                
              
              Comments
                
                
              

                                
                    
                    --None--
                    Visiant
                    Tessellate
                

                
                    --None--
                    Internal
                Trade Show
                Website
                Direct Marketing
                Social Media
                Other

```
body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 85%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}


input[type="text"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

select,
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Lato";
}

#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #B9B9B9;
  color: #959595;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  display: block;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #f78e2a;
}

@media (max-width: 426px) {
  label {
    width: 98%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 426px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -5%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}

[data-valid] .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: green;
}

[data-valid="valid"] .fa {
  color: green;
}

[data-valid="error"] .fa {
  color: red;
}

.error {
  display: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(150%);
}

[data-valid="error"] .error {
  display: block;
}

input#sub:not([disabled]){
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #F68D2E;;
} 

function phoneNumber(phone)  {
  var phoneno = /^\d{9,11}$/;

  console.log("PHONE: "+phoneno.test(phone));
  return phoneno.test(phone);
}

$('input[type="tel"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#phone')) {
      if (phoneNumber($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works");
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works")
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works")

  }
});


function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  console.log("email: "+re.test(email));
  return re.test(email);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");

      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works 1")
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works 2");
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works 3");
  }
});


test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val()
      && $("#last_name").val()
      && $("#email").val()
      && $("#phone").val()
      && $("#city").val()
      && $("#state").val()
      && $("#company").val()
      && $("#comments").val()) {

    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

Comment: HTML5 validation makes it easy...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val()
      && $("#last_name").val()
      && (validateEmail($("#email").val()))
      && (phoneNumber($("#phone").val()))
      && $("#phone").val()
      && $("#city").val()
      && $("#state").val()
      && $("#company").val()
      && $("#comments").val()) {

    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled") && $("#sub2").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah there are two option one custom create your validation script another use jquery validater plugin(which provides everything in opinion)

so the basic idea for creating your own script would be checking the validation function every-time an input feild is changed or filled something like

```
$('input[type=text], input[type=phone],input[type=email]').on('change onkeypress ',function(){
YourValidationFunction();
})
```

or

just use

https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/